# Get dropdown menu in google extensions popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I try create extension to google chrome - this extension must create button, that will show popup when pressed. That popup will contain input form,  i think, and when i start inputting request string that will show dropdown menu with 'fast results' of search. So.. i can't find way to do it. I have one idea - i create  and  and connect them. With help of JS i add s of received data from google. But, this is do not work  if packed as google extension (see proof:  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161302 ). Have you any idea? 
P.S. Sorry me for two points: my bad english (not my native language) and, maybe, bad question - i just trying to start work with JS and google extensions. Thx for all.

Comment: It would help if you share your code

Answer (score 0):

You see in that bug that it is marked as fixed in June. This means it's fixed in whatever was the development version then. It will take some time until it reaches Stable.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but it still not working in google chrome beta. Also, i looking for another ways.